# Does 'It would be very appreciated' contain any obligation for the future?

Tags: politeness

I have a feeling that if I ask for something that I really need and would welcome, I can add 'very appreciated', but then I feel myself obligated to somehow react in addition after getting what I need, i.e. to **express** my appreciation.

So, if you ask person to do something and add 'it would be very appreciated', what is the correct response after the person does it? Is a response really expected?

Comment: I've tidied this question, but it is more to do with etiquette than language, and doesn't fit into the ELU topics. It could conceivably fall into the "Other practical problems you encounter or face while learning English" topic on ELL, so I'll pass it over there (but even on ELL, it may not be a good fit).

Comment: *"It would be very appreciated"* is a poor wording. In the UK we would say *"It would be very* **much** *appreciated"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It would be very appreciated" is just another way of saying "Please".

As you your future response: that's just a matter of etiquette, not language. If you say "please", and someone does what you asked, it is polite to say "thank you".

So yes, a "thank you" or similar would be expected afterwards.